# CoreOS member node will not start when using "etcdctl member add"

Tags: docker, coreos, etcd

I am trying to add an additional etcd node to my CoreOS cluster with the command "etcdctl member add core2 http://172.31.12.183:2380" but this command leaves my new node as unstarted and my cluster is unhealthy because of this.  How do I fix this or start my new node after I run the etcdctl member add command?  Here is the output of when I run this command and the cluster status afterwards:

```
core@ip-172-31-12-183 ~ $ etcdctl member add core2 http://172.31.12.183:2380
Added member named core2 with ID 4d14f3cb088a2f54 to cluster

ETCD_NAME="core2"
ETCD_INITIAL_CLUSTER="core2=http://172.31.12.183:2380,ec2c8c9d2cf141cf9657e98b260895a5=http://172.31.12.182:2380"
ETCD_INITIAL_CLUSTER_STATE="existing"
core@ip-172-31-12-183 ~ $ etcdctl member list
4d14f3cb088a2f54[unstarted]: peerURLs=http://172.31.12.183:2380
aedf0a441a723d8a: name=ec2c8c9d2cf141cf9657e98b260895a5 peerURLs=http://172.31.12.182:2380 clientURLs=http://172.31.12.182:2379,http://172.31.12.182:4001
core@ip-172-31-12-183 ~ $ etcdctl cluster-health
member 4d14f3cb088a2f54 is unreachable: no available published client urls
member aedf0a441a723d8a is unhealthy: got unhealthy result from http://172.31.12.182:2379
cluster is unhealthy
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Simply to say, the steps you made to add member are wrong.**
As in the official [docs](https://coreos.com/etcd/docs/latest/runtime-configuration.html),  the steps to `add a new member to a 1-node cluster` which I assume is your scenario :

1. start the first node
2. run `etcdctl member add`
3. start the second node with cluster related options

**So according to your case:**

before `core2` started, run =>

```
etcdctl member add core2 http://172.31.12.183:2380
```

then, start `core2` with cluster related options =>

```
./etcd --name core2 --initial-advertise-peer-urls http://172.31.12.183:2380 \
  --listen-peer-urls http://172.31.12.183:2380 \
  --listen-client-urls http://172.31.12.183:2379 \
  --advertise-client-urls http://172.31.12.183:2379 \
  --initial-cluster core2=http://172.31.12.183:2380,ec2c8c9d2cf141cf9657e98b260895a5=http://172.31.12.182:2380 \
  --initial-cluster-state existing
```